# How to get matrix diagonal length?

Tags: math, matrix

Is there a formula that would get me the length of a matrix's diagonal in units? For example if the matrix is 3x3, the diagonal length would be 3.

Comment: In what language?  It's not a formula, it's an attribute of the matrix. That's like saying - What formula do I use to tell that a blue car is blue?  However, in general, if the two dimensions are equal you could use either one of the dimension's lengths.

Comment: It's been a long day... May I suggest...   a cup of coffee or a brisk walk in the park? Either of these should get you head back in operating mode ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The diagonal of an NxN matrix is always N.

The diagonal of a non-square matricies is `min(nrows, ncols)`.

Matricies can have units (e.g. stiffness matrix in finite elements for mechanics has physical units of force/length), but I'm not sure how you mean it.

Comment: I'll give you +1... you'll have it right up until the time the question gets deleted ;).

Comment: Wrong. Non-square matrices still have the concept of a [main diagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal)!